# Duplicate Events in Message Broker

Tags: events, monitoring, esb, messagebroker

In Message Broker (v8.0.0.0) we are using the event monitoring framework to drive our flow-level auditing. We're looking at three types of audit - start, and and rollback; and the corresponding transaction.Start/End/Rollback events as defined by Message Broker are being used for this.

For rollback, within each flow, we have a generic exception handler that's catching the exception terminal from the input node, does some processing, and then throws an exception again. This means we get a rollback event from broker and the original message is backed out to DLQ.

However, for these cases, we are getting four events instead of the two expected (i.e. Start and Rollback). There is an extra Start event and an End event being generated.

I looked around and there's a possible duplicate of this issue in the MQSeries forums, where somebody suggested that this is because the message is being backed out. (Link at the end of the post.)

Can anybody suggest a mitigation/workaround? I looked at the event messages themselves and there's no way of distinguishing one from the other.

[MQSeries Forum Thread](http://www.mqseries.net/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?p=388883&sid=371c10c3114f36de3aba98f393ee21c4)

Answer (score 0):

The extra start and end is because it is actually the MQ input node that sends the message to the DLQ, not MQ itself.

Since the transaction start message is raised before the node knows that it needs to DLQ the message we also need a transaction event to close the open transaction.

In fact we do this work under it's own MQ transaction so the events to correspond with the actual transaction boundaries, it is just that in your case the message never makes the flow on the last iteration.

It would be nice to distinguish between a successful transaction and one where we performed a back, like we do with rollback events but IIB does not currently allow for this.

I would suggest raising it as a requirement at the following URI:

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/?PROD_ID=532